# How to write the build date in the nodejs package.json?

Tags: node.js, build, package.json

Is it possible to automatically update package.json with the build time when doing npm run build so that I get this:

```
{
...
    "build": "2020-09-04T12:12", 
...
}
```

Comment: I believe you are looking for `"build":"npm run build; date"`

Answer (score -1):

I had small script for it laying around so I packaged it https://www.npmjs.com/package/kvjson

usage

```
npm i -D kvjson
./node_modules/.bin/kvjson <file> <key> <value>
```